# Changing Pages in OnTouch

Tags: java, android, android-intent, touch-event

I know how to make it so you will open a new page onClick but when I put the same code into onTouch it doesnt work? This is the code I have... any help for me if I click on the error I get a message saying "The constructor Intent(Tab3, Class) is undefined" and it wants me to set it to "= new Intent" but that doesnt make sence to me.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        if(rect2.contains((int) event.getX(),(int) event.getY()))
        {
            Intent SectionManager = new Intent (this, SectionManager.class);
            startActivity (SectionManager);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

EDIT
more information on my code!

```
public class Tab3 extends View implements OnTouchListener
{
    LinearLayout myLayout;
    int x1, x2, y1, y2, x, y;
    // x, y;
    Rect rect2 = new Rect();

    public Tab3(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super (context, attrs);

        myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);

        x1 = 0;
        x2 = 300;               //1280 by 748
        y1 = 0;
        y2 = 300;




        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true); 
        setOnTouchListener(this);
        requestFocus();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Paint blue = new Paint();
        blue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawRect(rect2, blue);
        rect2.set(x1, y1, x2, y2);

        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        if(rect2.contains((int) event.getX(),(int) event.getY()))
        {
            Intent SectionManager = new Intent (Tab3.this, SectionManager.class);
            startActivity (SectionManager);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `this` doesn't seem to be a context in there. 
Could that be the case?

Comment: I don't know why it happens, but i faced the same error and I only changed my explicit intent to implicit intent and error was removed
Try this

Comment: I know that the `this` us need in onTouch so Im not sure, If I delete that I need to add a `null` there then I still have the error on the "startActivity" saying "The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type Tab3"

Comment: read my answer as to why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your context is wrong you need to use `YourClassName.this` inside there not just `this`. currently `this` means the view aka `Tab3` which is not the context

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
            .
            all your activity stuff here
            .
            .
public class Tab3 extends View implements OnTouchListener{

LinearLayout myLayout;
int x1, x2, y1, y2, x, y;
// x, y;
Rect rect2 = new Rect();

public Tab3(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super (context, attrs);

    myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);

    x1 = 0;
    x2 = 300;               //1280 by 748
    y1 = 0;
    y2 = 300;




    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true); 
    setOnTouchListener(this);
    requestFocus();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Paint blue = new Paint();
    blue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawRect(rect2, blue);
    rect2.set(x1, y1, x2, y2);

    invalidate();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
{
    if(rect2.contains((int) event.getX(),(int) event.getY()))
    {
        Intent SectionManager = new Intent (MyActivity.this, SectionManager.class);
        startActivity (SectionManager);
    }
    return true;
}
} //end Tab3 Class
} //end MyActivity
```

Tab3 is a sub class of MyActivity now and you should be able to do MyActivity.this

Comment: so your saying that I should have `Intent SectionManager = new Intent (SectionManager.this, SectionManager.class);` ? because that just gives me a differert error... saying "No enclosing instance of the type SectionManager is accessible in scope"

Comment: no `(TheClassNameYouAreCurrentlyIn.this, SectionManager.class)` is what you want, you might even be able to use `getApplicationContext()` in there not sure just depends on your code

Comment: I know have `Intent SectionManager = new Intent (Tab3.this, SectionManager.class);
   startActivity (SectionManager);` and I am still getting two erros and the same two... Im sorry if this is a waste of your rime but I really need to firgure this out.

Comment: ok so thats why its a view, just create a shared preference variable or something persistent and set that to the context when the application starts. OR you could move that view class into an activity class as like a sub class then you would be able to get the context that way

Comment: COuld you give me an example of some sort by any chance , that would be greatly appresheated

Comment: Thanks for all your help! What do I need to put where you said "all your activity stuff here" ?

Comment: just like you would in a normal activity is what you would do here, I am guessing that view is in a separate class file so where ever that view class is being used in one of your activities is where you should move that to